# Additional foreach loops cause PHP to crash with "Allowed memory size exhausted" fatal error

Tags: php, csv, memory, foreach

I'm trying to parse products in my company's store for indexing in our Google Base. I was given a .CSV with one column of products and another column of issue for that product. I shouldn't index the products that have particular issues with them.

What I did was create a function that takes .csv and outputs a "nonIndexedProducts" array.

If you're familiar with Google Base (in Opencart) they use a `foreach` loop to go through and display all the products. I added another `foreach` loop inside there that goes through each of the "nonIndexProducts" and if the product name matches the nonIndexProduct, I have a conditional statement that doesn't do anything. If the product name doesn't match then it is indexed and displayed.

Now after much tweaking and getting to that point, I'm running into this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20971484 bytes) in /home/xxxx/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_feed_google_base.php on line 31
```

So I know there's too much going on and obviously I don't want to increase the memory size. I have a couple hundred products and only 160 products that don't need to be indexed. I understand that's still huge though, but what's the best way to go about this?

Here are my loops (but mind you everything else is what Google Base provided for me, I only added the lines where '// I added' is denoted):

```
    public function index() {
    if ($this->config->get('google_base_status')) { 
        $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
        $output .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">';
        $output .= '<channel>';
        $output .= '<title>' . $this->config->get('config_name') . '</title>'; 
        $output .= '<description>' . $this->config->get('config_meta_description') . '</description>';
        $output .= '<link>' . HTTP_SERVER . '</link>';

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

        // I added
        $nonIndexArray = $this->getNonIndexedProducts("http://EXAMPLE.com/catalog/controller/feed/product_issues.csv");

        foreach ($products as $product) {

          // I added
          foreach ($nonIndexedArray as $nonProduct) {

            // I added
            if ($product['name'] !== $nonProduct ) {

                if ($product['description']) {
                    $output .= '<item>';
                    $output .= '<title>' . $product['name'] . '</title>';
                    $output .= '<link>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</link>';
                    $output .= '<description>' . $product['description'] . '</description>';
                    $output .= '<g:brand>' . html_entity_decode($product['manufacturer'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</g:brand>';
                    $output .= '<g:condition>new</g:condition>';
                    $output .= '<g:id>' . $product['product_id'] . '</g:id>';

                    if ($product['image']) {
                        $output .= '<g:image_link>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], 500, 500) . '</g:image_link>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<g:image_link>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 500, 500) . '</g:image_link>';
                    }

                    $output .= '<g:mpn>' . $product['model'] . '</g:mpn>';

                    $currencies = array(
                        'USD', 
                        'EUR', 
                        'GBP'
                    );

                    if (in_array($this->currency->getCode(), $currencies)) {
                        $currency_code = $this->currency->getCode();
                        $currency_value = $this->currency->getValue();
                    } else {
                        $currency_code = 'USD';
                        $currency_value = $this->currency->getValue('USD');
                    }

                    if ((float)$product['special']) {
                        $output .= '<g:price>' . $this->currency->format($product['special'], $currency_code, $currency_value, false) . '</g:price>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<g:price>' . $this->currency->format($product['price'], $currency_code, $currency_value, false) . '</g:price>';
                    }

                    $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product['product_id']);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $path = $this->getPath($category['category_id']);

                        if ($path) {
                            $string = '';

                            foreach (explode('_', $path) as $path_id) {
                                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                                if ($category_info) {
                                    if (!$string) {
                                        $string = $category_info['name'];
                                    } else {
                                        $string .= ' &gt; ' . $category_info['name'];
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            $output .= '<g:product_type>' . $string . '</g:product_type>';
                        }
                    }

                    $output .= '<g:quantity>' . $product['quantity'] . '</g:quantity>';
                    $output .= '<g:upc>' . $product['upc'] . '</g:upc>'; 
                    $output .= '<g:weight>' . $this->weight->format($product['weight'], $product['weight_class_id']) . '</g:weight>';
                    $output .= '<g:availability>' . ($product['quantity'] ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock') . '</g:availability>';
                    $output .= '</item>';
                }



            } else {

            }

        }
        }

        $output .= '</channel>'; 
        $output .= '</rss>';    

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
        $this->response->setOutput($output);


    }
}
```

Comment: One bad solution is to increase your memory limit, the other one is to make sure you don't use that much memory. Can you post the loops to check on the code?

Comment: How much memory do you have at your Server ? I think its a really small value :/

Comment: @thanpa I added it above

Comment: @Svetlio It says in the error message. 32MB doesn't sound like a particularly small allocation for a PHP process. There may be something wrong in the actual code. (Also, I don't know much about Google Base, but presumably it's some kind of database, so I'd guess there would be a query/set-based solution to this problem rather than doing manual looping in PHP...)

Comment: Personally, I'd remove the non-indexed products from `$products` prior to entering the product loop, rather than having a deep conditional.  That would save at least two layers of nesting and may reduce your memory foot print.

Comment: @MattGibson I saw that number just I want to asked if Andrea has set it ..

Comment: @MattGibson the file is in .php because Opencart, the e-commerce platform, is written in PHP and it has to be done on the site side. What this code basically does is generate a webpage that Google knows how to parse and grabs the metadata and other info from each Product that is displayed. What I'm doing is creating checks to remove the product so Google doesn't see it.

Comment: @bishop sorry, I don't follow. What do you mean remove before entering product loop? Where would I put it then?

Comment: @AndreaRose I know perfectly well OpenCart and its vQmod .. Like Matt Gibson mention 32MB is your allowed memory. But as I know vQmods behaviour this is not enough and you need to increase that number. An option is with ini_set or with setting php.ini file (depend on your server)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying that if you're getting your products out of a database (in your `$this->model_catalog_product->getProducts()` call) then there may be a way of solving this at the database level, e.g. something that boils down to `SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE id NOT IN (some list)`, so you wouldn't need to be doing anything like so much work.

Comment: @MattGibson Ah I see, I get what you mean. What is the syntax in SQL for the "NOT IN" part if I give it my array?

Comment: The syntax is `...WHERE ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`. Or you can do something like add an extra (boolean) column to your product table of "is_indexed", then set it up and just do e.g. `SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE is_indexed = 0`, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment with an example. I'd start by reverting your code to the starting point, then removing the non index products prior to iterating over them:

```
// get the products, this is original code
$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

// remove non-indexed products, this is your custom code to
// eliminate products you don't care about
$nonIndexArray = $this->getNonIndexedProducts("http://EXAMPLE.com/catalog/controller/feed/product_issues.csv");
foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
    if (in_array($product['name'], $nonIndexArray)) {
        unset($products[$i]);
    }
}

// now resume the original code
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($product['description']) {
```

This might allow the script to run within the memory constraint you have.  Or it might not.  Either way, it looks to be a cleaner approach owing to fewer inserted lines and fewer loops.

---

*Edit* I suspect your `getNonIndexedProducts` function is consuming most of your memory (like loading the entire CSV file into RAM). That function can probably be optimized, but you might just want a quick fix... which is bumping up your memory to the max:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Comment: It does run within the constraint, however, it's displaying all the products and didn't remove any. I checked my code and the nonIndexArray still contains the correct products I want removed.

Comment: I tried the `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and it did not work. Is there any way to possibly just create another file that does the "getNonIndexProducts" functionality and maybe just output the array to a file? Then just call to the file to pull the array out in the google_base.php?

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish the goal. Too many to list. Debug the little loop I've created here to find what's causing the `if` statement not match (and therefore unset the product) and you'll be golden.

Comment: Thank you, your initial fix worked-- there was a few too many unclosed brackets that were giving me weird errors and I suppose closing before that new foreach was even being used. :)

Comment: Hey, glad it's working! Thanks for accepting, don't forget to up-vote too. :)